# What’s the purpose of an exclamation mark at the start of a block comment?

Tags: c++, class, comments

I have a header file in `c++`, where the declaration of the functions have block comments that start with "`!`" exclamation marks.

Example

```cpp
class test{
 public:
        /*! @fn test::test()
            @brief The basic constructor, which initializes the _test handle.
        */
        test();

        /*! @fn test::upload(std::string url)
            @brief A function to execute a http POST request with the given url and image.

            @param[in] url The url we are POSTing to
            @return The response of the server
        */
        std::string upload(std::string url);
}
```

Also, it changes the color of the comment in VSCode like this:

[image]

What’s the purpose of the exclamation marks at the start of those comments?

Comment: From the perspective of C++, it doesn't mean anything. The contents of a comment are arbitrary. What's actually happening is that your IDE is treating the ! inside the comment as significant. The exact meaning and notational scheme it's working with therefore depend on your toolset and how it's been configured.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These comments are for the [Doxygen system](https://doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) that automatically generates documentation from code.